# How do I place a multi-term command in the background on xonsh?

Tags: xonsh

For instance, I want to do the following, but it fails:

```
$ echo "mytext bla" > test.txt&
$ rm test.txt
/bin/rm: cannot remove 'test.txt': No such file or directory
```

The actual command I am trying to implement is:

```
ionice -c 3 dropbox start&
```

Comment: works for me with xonsh 0.3.3.

Comment: @meuh I am on xonsh/0.5.12

Comment: Try adding a space before `&`

Comment: Brilliant, it works!  But why?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, proposed by @mitnk (see above) is to add a space before the `&`, like so:

`echo "mytext bla" > test.txt &`

Comment: Apparently xonsh is not recognizing the backgrounding token `&` before executing the redirection; likely creating a file named `test.txt&`